# Strechting Content to 100% with Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap

At the moment I am doing the following to get a div stretch across the complete width:

```
<div class="container-fluid banner">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="span12">
                <img src="image.png"> 
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In my example, I'm wrapping the content in a `container-fluid` to force the content to stretch to full width.

As far as I know, Bootstrap doesn't provide a better and easier way to stretch content to full width and my approach has some disadvantages. Are there better ways to accomplish this?

Comment: What is the aim of that wrapping div? The inner content widths won't be affected, per se. So is the purpose for styling a background?

Comment: My intension is to have a banner which takes the full width of the browser's window.

Comment: Perhaps then add an extra div at the top of the document for that, such as is done on this Bootstrap example page: http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/examples/hero.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you use some css reset so you have to look what you have done there with body tag, after that as it was said before use

```
 .container {width: 100%}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change the `container` styles if you wish.

```
.container {width: 100%}
```

You would have to make other changes, of course; but whatever is done in CSS can be undone (well, almost everything).